# Is it possible to make body onload event faster?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this code to submit a form automatically on page load, but it takes like 20 seconds in order to do the submit after the page is completely loaded.

Am I doing anything wrong here?
If not, how to bypass that 20 seconds delay?
Can we make the body `onload` event faster?

The code:

```
<html>
<body onload="document.forms['loginform'].submit();">
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" action="https://login.url.com" method="post" style="visibility:hidden">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="hhh">
    <input type="text" value="username" id="login_field" name="username">
    <input type="password" value="pass" id="password_field" name="password">
                <input type="hidden" value="" id="password_strength" name="password_strength">
                <input type="hidden" value="/index.php" id="sendto" name="sendto">
    <button id="btn_logon" type="submit"><span>Login</span></button>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Surely the 20 second delay *after* the submit is due to slow processing on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load event is fired after all dependencies of the page - images, externa resources, etc. have been loaded. The event you should watch for is the one that gets fired when the DOM is ready - `DOMContentLoaded` which has been standardized in HTML5.

For a cross-browser solution, pick an implementation from any of the existing JavaScript libraries like MooTools, jQuery, Dojo, etc.

This [link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-load-and-domcontentloaded) contains one implementation. If your DOM content is too big, and downloading and parsing just that is taking time, then consider adding your script right after the `<form>` itself.

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" action=".." method="post">
...
</form>
<script>
    // submits the form right after it is parsed
    document.forms['loginform'].submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Standardized =) Who cares, right? All the browsers do it and there's more than two implementations. Why do we even have a W3C to standardize stuff? They're 3 always years behind!

Comment: so,how to watch for the DOM. i am still newbie to javascript.plus adding a javascript library, i think this will need more time to load the library itself??

Comment: I support the efforts of W3C. There are few glitches and inconsistencies here and there, but when you consider how big the entire specification is, it seems like they're going a great job. Without a spec and a governing body, and the lack of normalizing libraries like jQuery, things could be a lot worse. We'd probably be writing a new site for each browser out there, just like we do for mobile apps.

Comment: @alhoseany - see this [link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-load-and-domcontentloaded#the-crossbrowser-domcontentloaded-handling-code) for a cross-browser function called named `bindReady` that does what you want. Or just put your script to submit the form after closing the form tag as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Anurag mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5774912/8804293), the `DOMContentLoaded` event would be better as it "doesn't wait for other things like images, subframes, and async scripts to finish loading" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)).

To implement this in your code, you should remove the `onload` attribute from the `<body>` tag and instead use this code:

```js
<script>
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => document.forms['loginform'].submit());
</script>
```

Or, better yet, grab the form by its id:

```js
<script>
addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => document.getElementById("loginform").submit());
</script>
```